# Debian Wheezy service php5 unrecognized

Tags: php, linux, debian, apache2, php-5.5

**Sigh** I have been trying trying to fix this problem for days now BUT haven't found any solutions for it. I have even reinstalled my VPS. Didnt help either.
I have installed Apache2 and `PHP5` 
`apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt` 
BUT when i run the following command it tells me that service `php5` is not recognized.

And [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) is the tutorial that I have followed.

This is what it looks like:

```
root@vps380619:/etc/php5/cli# service php5 restart
php5: unrecognized service
root@vps380619:/etc/php5/cli# service php restart
php: unrecognized service
root@vps380619:/etc/php5/cli# service --status-all
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ - ]  bootlogs
 [ ? ]  bootmisc.sh
 [ ? ]  checkfs.sh
 [ ? ]  checkroot-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot.sh
 [ - ]  console-setup
 [ + ]  cron
 [ - ]  hostname.sh
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  kbd
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ - ]  motd
 [ ? ]  mountall-bootclean.sh
 [ ? ]  mountall.sh
 [ ? ]  mountdevsubfs.sh
 [ ? ]  mountkernfs.sh
 [ ? ]  mountnfs-bootclean.sh
 [ ? ]  mountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  mtab.sh
 [ ? ]  mysql
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ - ]  procps
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ - ]  rmnologin
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ + ]  udev
 [ ? ]  udev-mtab
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ + ]  winbind
root@vps380619:/etc/php5/cli#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP only has a service if it is run under FPM. Unless you have installed and are using PHP-FPM (which you wouldn't be, considering you're using Apache and `mod-php`), PHP is spawned per-request instead of having a daemon to listen to calls. Instead, you should be restarting Apache, as stated later in the tutorial:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to to do:

```
service apache2 restart
```

if you want to run php from the command line use:

```
php <filename.php>
```